# show only last 4 digits in bank account using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help with Javascript. I need to replace however many characters there are previous to the last 4 digits of a text field that contains bank account number. I have searched through the net on this, but cannot find one code that works. I did find a code here on stackoverflow, which was regarding credit card,

```
new String('x', creditCard.Length - 4) + creditCard.Substring(creditCard.Length - 4);
```

I just replaced the creditCard with accounNumObject:

```
var accounNumObject = document.getElementById("bankAcctNum")
```

The input is pretty simple.

```
<cfinput type="text" name="bankAcctNum" id="bankAcctNum" maxlength="25" size="25" value="#value#" onblur="hideAccountNum();">
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To replace a string with `x` except for the last four characters in JavaScript, you could use (assuming `str` holds the string)...

```
var trailingCharsIntactCount = 4;

str = new Array(str.length - trailingCharsIntactCount + 1).join('x')
       + str.slice(-trailingCharsIntactCount);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FHG9e/).

You could also use a regular expression...

```
str = str.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x');
```

If you want to add the `4` from a variable, construct the regex with the `RegExp` constructor.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QmdZ3/).

If you're fortunate enough to have the support, also...

```
const trailingCharsIntactCount = 4;

str = 'x'.repeat(str.length - trailingCharsIntactCount)
        + str.slice(-trailingCharsIntactCount);
```

Polyfill for `String.prototype.repeat()` is [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill).

Comment: The above will work. Do bear in mind though that the full bank account number will still be available in the source, and with script turned off, so this is superficial security. If this is important you might consider doing this serverside.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fiddle showing what you're asking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/eGFqM/1/

```
<input id='account' value='abcdefghijklmnop'/>
<br/>
<input id='account_changed'/>
```

```
var account = document.getElementById('account');
var changed = document.getElementById('account_changed');

changed.value = new Array(account.value.length-3).join('x') + 
    account.value.substr(account.value.length-4, 4);
```

Edit: Updated fiddle to correct off by one problem pointed out by alex

Comment: That code has an off by one problem. You need to add `1` to the `Array` constructor's argument.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with all above solutions.I just had one another approach.

```js
const maskAccountId = (accountId) => {
 if (accountId) { /** Condition will only executes if accountId is *not* undefined, null, empty, false or 0*/
  const accountIdlength = accountId.length;
  const maskedLength = accountIdlength - 4; /** Modify the length as per your wish */
  let newString = accountId;
  for (let i = 0; i < accountIdlength; i++) {
   if (i < maskedLength) {
    newString = newString.replace(accountId[i], '*');
   }
  }
  return newString;
 } else return /**Will handle if no string is passed */
}

console.log(maskAccountId('egrgrgry565yffvfdfdfdfdfgrtrt4t4'));
```