# Show last few characters when data binding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand how data binding works in this simple example, however I'm curious on how you could limit the output to display only the last 4 characters of whatever number you put in, instead of the entire number:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="number" placeholder="Enter a long number here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{number}}!</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9795028/3556874

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the AngularJS [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) docs you could do:

```
<h1>Hello {{number | limitTo: -4}}!</h1>
```

Or see this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OZDbZu5ogJIePr5yvXQC?p=preview) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For that you have to write a Custom filter

    **This is the Example:-**

    'use strict';
    var toDoAppFilters = angular.module('toDoAppFilters',[]) ;

    toDoAppFilters.filter('truncate', function() {
        return function(input,length) {
            return (input.length > length ? input.substring(0, length) : input );
        };
    });
  And call like this 
<h1>Hello {{number | truncate:20}}!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in this way.

```
<div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="number" placeholder="Enter a long number here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{number |limitTo : -4: number.length}}!</h1>
    </div>
```

Please refer this more info [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

or you can put custom [filer](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) in template



EDIT CODE :

With angular 1.0.7, the **limitTo** filter is work with only **Array**.
For your requirement,you need to implement custom filter.
Please check it [here](https://github.com/angular/code.angularjs.org/blob/master/1.0.7/docs/partials/api/ng.filter:limitTo.html) for more details.

JS :

```
angular.module("test",[])
.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) { 
        $scope.number = ""; 

}).filter("limitToCustom",function(){

    return function(actualData,number){
        console.log(number)
        var arrData = actualData.split("");
        return  actualData.slice(-number);

    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<div  ng-controller="testCtrl" class="container">

    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="number"  placeholder="Enter a long number here">
      <hr>{{number}}
      <h1>Hello {{number |limitToCustom : 4 }}!</h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZOZy0qNPsuCD3ObZKMBC?p=preview)

Comment: I've gone ahead and used `{{number |limitTo : -4 : number.length}}` however it's still not working and only displaying the full number.. is there something I am missing?

Comment: Edit: I am using angularjs 1.0.7 not 1.4.2.

Comment: But in your post you given  1.4.2

Comment: I have added EDIT CODE for 1.0.7.Please check it